# TF-IDF Matrix and Regression

Tags: regression, text-mining

I am trying to build a regression model based on some tweets that my company put on our company feed. I would like to transform all of the tweets, and use them to tell me which word(s) were most important (if at all) in response rates (ie. people commenting or re-tweeting). Is this possible? Would I just transform the corpus to TF-DF / TF-IDF and fit a regular regression?

Comment: This is possible. You could certainly try it.